# SQL Query (inner join, and duplicate results)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm completely new to SQL, just trying to speed up my job by making a few queries that can help me.

My example code (I restricted the query to one order, to show the problem):

```
SELECT dbo.BI.nmdos, dbo.BI.OBRANO, dbo.bi.ref
, dbo.BI.design, dbo.BI.LOBS, dbo.BI.qtt, dbo.sa.stock
FROM dbo.BI
LEFT JOIN dbo.SA on dbo.SA.REF=dbo.BI.REF
WHERE dbo.BI.FECHADA=0 AND dbo.BI.LOBS <> 'S' 
AND dbo.BI.QTT >= 1 AND dbo.BI.nmdos = 'Encomenda Cliente' 
AND dbo.BI.obrano = 2496
```

My result:

```
Encomenda Cliente   2496                        rty     5.0000  NULL
Encomenda Cliente   2496    01103402            TONER OKI P/B4000       1.0000  0.000
Encomenda Cliente   2496    PC                  PORTES - COMPRAS        2.0000  1429.000
Encomenda Cliente   2496    CXDVDNORMBL         CAIXA DE DVD NORMAL PRETO FOSCO - 14MM (100)        10.0000 4.000
Encomenda Cliente   2496    CXDVDNORMBL         CAIXA DE DVD NORMAL PRETO FOSCO - 14MM (100)        10.0000 0.000
Encomenda Cliente   2496    CXDVDNORMBL         CAIXA DE DVD NORMAL PRETO FOSCO - 14MM (100)        10.0000 0.000
```

My problem:
I need to remove the last 2 lines with the product code "CXDVDNORMBL" that have stock = 0.

What should I do?

Ty

Comment: And adding `AND dbo.sa.stock > 0` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Do you want to remove **any** duplicated or just those with zero `stock`?

Comment: You're getting this because you have three rows in `dbo.SA` with `.REF = 'CXDVDNORMBL'`. Why do you have them if you want to remove them?

Comment: I need to see the line when the product is 0, but I found the error. The dbo.sa.stock can have stock for several warehouses, and when more that one warehouse was filled on the prodcut file, the query showed that extra warehouses lines (CXDVDNORMBL had movements in 3 warehouses), so I added a where statement for the main warehouse. To bad I only found this out after wasting other ppl time... Sry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dbo.SA.stock > 0 to your join condition. This way it will only join on rows from SA that have some stock.

```
SELECT dbo.BI.nmdos, dbo.BI.OBRANO, dbo.bi.ref, dbo.BI.design, dbo.BI.LOBS, dbo.BI.qtt, dbo.sa.stock
FROM dbo.BI
LEFT JOIN dbo.SA on dbo.SA.REF=dbo.BI.REF AND dbo.SA.stock > 0
WHERE dbo.BI.FECHADA=0 AND dbo.BI.LOBS<>'S' AND dbo.BI.QTT>=1 AND dbo.BI.nmdos='Encomenda Cliente' AND dbo.BI.obrano=2496
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to delete rows from an order when those products are out of stock? Just run another query that deletes the same thing that you selected before but add WHERE stock = 0?

Not sure it's wise to completely remove those rows though. You might need that information later, for instance if you're going to send an email to the customer saying some items can't be included in their order, or just to log what customers have ordered (can still be very relevant information even if it was never delivered). Therefore I think it might be better to just filter out any rows with 0 stock whenever you do a select for it. Or, if you really want those rows out of the orders table for some reason, put them in another table called outOfStock with the order ID linked to it.